# Cast not shown correctly

Tags: c++

In the sample code below, why

`a` is assigned as `004609CC` instead of `004609C0`?
I was expecting a,b, and c to point to the same address.
And why dynamic_Cast(a) changes the address to `004609C0`

```
class A1
{public:
    unsigned a1;
    int a2;
    virtual ~A1() { }
};

class B1
{public:
    unsigned b1;
    int b2;
    virtual ~B1() { }
};

class C1 : public B1, public A1
{public:
    unsigned c1;
    virtual ~C1(){}
};


int main()
{
    C1* c = new C1;
    A1* a = c;
    B1* b = c;


    std::cout << static_cast<void*>(a) << "\n"; //004609CC Why not 004609C0?
    std::cout << static_cast<void*>(b) << "\n"; //004609C0
    std::cout << static_cast<void*>(c) << "\n"; //004609C0
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<C1*>(a) << "\n"; //004609C0  


//  delete b;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at the object layout of objects with multiple inheritance you'll basically have the base subobjects somewhere in the object. For example, the object could look something like this:

```
+-------+
+ +---+ +
| | B | |
| +---+ |
| +---+ |
| | A | |
| +---+ |
| C mem |
+-------+
```

When you have a pointer to a `B` or an `A` object it doesn't know that it is embedded into an object with multiple inheritance. Correspondingly either the pointer to the `B` subobject or the pointer to the `A` subobject cannot have the same address as the `C` object. Potentially, neither object has the same address as `C`, e.g., when the ABI specifies that the `C` members have to precede the base class subobjects (I'm not aware of any system which does this, though).

Comment: But how is pointer to a supposed to get a hint that the address it is pointing to is an object as a result of multiple inheritance and it should point to base+12 bytes? In other words how is the statement `a=c` supposed to know that it should point to `c+12` bytes ? How does it get this hint from?

Comment: @anurag86: the compiler does know where the `A` subobject of a `C` object is located and it will do the correct pointer adjustment when implicitly converting a `C` object to an `A` subobject.

Comment: I initially thought it gets hint through RTTI. I removed virtual keyword but still i see the same behavior.

Comment: @anurag86: the offset of the `A` subobject from the address of a `C` subobject is, obviously, statically known. There is no need for RTTI. Since the conversion from a `C*` to an `A*` is an implicit conversion, the reverse conversion can also be done without RTTI: it just needs to apply the offset in the opposite direction.